# Infer parameter type depending on other parameters in method

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Suppose I have this function declaration:

```
function foo<T extends {}>(bar: Array<{ key: keyof T, value: any, otherParam: string}>): T[]
```

And I have this interface:

```
interface C {
    d: string
    e: number
}
```

When I call foo like this:

```
foo<C>([{key: 'd', value: 'myValue', otherParam: 'other'}, {key: 'e', value: 100, otherParam: 'other'}])
```

I want to infer the type of the second parameter `value` and get rid of that awful `any`.

How can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) to convert `T` to your desired shape.

```
type Bar<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]: { key: P, value: T[P], otherParam: string }
}[keyof T];
```

Full solution:

```
type Bar<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]: { key: P, value: T[P], otherParam: string }
}[keyof T];

declare function foo<T extends object>(bar: Bar<T>[]): T[]

interface C {
    d: string
    e: number
}

foo<C>([{key: 'd', value: 'string', otherParam: 'other'}, {key: 'e', value: 100, otherParam: 'other'}])
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgJwDwBUB8UC8UDeAoKQqAbQAUoBLAOygGsIQB7AMyhQF0AuXOh70gDRQAbnAA2AVwjcUZdkMbAAFhASlEcALbcAzsATUA5lAC+eE8XpNWHANx48AEwgBjMYmjMJVF8AqMaZkZGVCgIAA9gCCpHHShGACMAK1dgNAAKBMRueGR0YnYAShkCh2oohGY4F2gAYVwCIkddfSNGwmkoKglNBNVzByCQ2oziHCtuAHJHSaFRSU7JvQMqQ1n45VV1BC0pxRUESZMhcb4oSYh1+aluAEYABnuFTbUNbXP91SOivCA)